# Gaining/losing 0 reputation on questions I've not asked or answered

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

It's a little confusing...

I voted on the bottom question but don't think I've touched the top one at all.

[image]

I have had the "reputation cap" tool-tip as in [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125066/you-reached-the-reputation-cap-for-this-post-but-its-not-my-post-and-cap-is-f) @Mat has just posted.

Comment: My first thought is that you downvoted an answer and then undid the vote.

Comment: @MatthewRead, that's possible, but I don't think I did this evening ( I'm UTC ) and it definitely didn't show up like this earlier in the day.

Comment: In my case all refer to posts I somehow interacted with: either I downvoted a question, or one of mine Community Wiki posts was voted on.

Comment: @Arjan, in that case Matthew Read is probably correct; I probably unupvoted or undownvoted... it'd be too much of a co-incidence otherwise.

Comment: It does show this 0 rep for questions I've downvoted here (and not un-downvoted). Tooltip on that `0` is wrong too, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125066/you-reached-the-reputation-cap-for-this-post-but-its-not-my-post-and-cap-is-f

Comment: It's logging the 0 rep you lose from downvoting. It started happening sometime today. It looks like a bug.

Comment: The reputation calculation system is under major changes recently - can't avoid bug or two slipping through - moderator will probably pop in soon to explain. :)

Comment: I get this when I downvote questions, could you verify?

Comment: @TomWijsman, you want me to go around down-voting people? The bottom question I down-voted so probably. Sha Dow Wiz Ard +1, I figured it was something like that...

Comment: @Ben: You could check whether you have down-votes on the freehand circled questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This did indeed change recently, we switched to an entirely different data source.  What you're seeing is the result of up/downvotes, or changes that resulted in no rep.

We'll exclude changes that had no rep impact starting with the next build.