# User popup shows self-accepted answer to a question I didn't ask + rep inconsistency

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gaining/losing 0 reputation on questions I've not asked or answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/gaining-losing-0-reputation-on-questions-ive-not-asked-or-answered)

So I just wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625206/apple-app-rejection-reason/9625870#9625870) that is currently accepted and has 1 up vote.

But as you can see in these screenshots it doesn't show any reputation gain in the rep statistics.

[image]

However the reputation change for today matches 60 + 15 from accept + 10 from up vote = 85:

[image]

If I hover over the 0 next to the question in the last screenshot it says "self-accepted answer".
But I didn't ask that question, and I really didn't accept my own answer ;-)