# I got no rep for an upvote while not hitting the rep cap?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, up-votes

[See my reputation page here:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal?tab=reputation)

[image: plus 10?]

Where is the `+10` rep for the upvote?
I did not seem to get **anything** for it.

What happened there? Is there something I missed?

[Here is the answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5822778/561731)

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822725/function-to-function-get-variable-array/5822778#5822778) isn't CW, and the daily limit is obviously not hit. No idea what caused this.

Comment: Maybe related [Gaining/losing 0 reputation on questions I've not asked or answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125065)

Comment: @Sathya possibly... but I did ask/answer this up/downvote.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We now show this not as a "no rep" series of votes, but the *actual* rep change and summarized as "User was removed" so it's very clear what happened here.

Answer (score 14):

That upvote was added 15 hours ago; 9 hours ago the user who upvoted you was deleted (I haven't checked to see why) - hence that vote ceased to be, and the net result is indeed zero. I'll check why it shows *at all* though - it would be less confusing if we displayed nothing.

Comment: Hmmmm odd... Let me know when you find out.

Comment: If it doesn't show up at all than you have again the problem that the reputation suddenly decreased by 10 with no trace of the reason in the reputation log.

Comment: Is this possibly why I lost 700 rep overnight? A bunch of users were deleted?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - your change was the result of fixing the double rep from migrations bug for all users last night: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124953/does-it-make-sense-that-migrated-questions-doubles-your-network-reputation/125102#125102

Comment: Ah, thanks @Nick. Not a huge deal, just wondering where it went. :-)