# Missing upvote rep?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, up-votes

I'm not sure if this is a [dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125152/i-got-no-rep-for-an-upvote) or not (if it is there were a few user's accounts deleted at once), but it looks like some of the rep associated with a few upvotes to a single answer were not added:

[image]

The one answer to the linked question above said that the user who upvoted was deleted, but really 3 different people within the last hour?

[My profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635634/m-babcock?tab=reputation)

Comment: Please, for the love of god, **LINK TO THE PROFILE** - otherwise we have *no* idea what part of who's rep screen you're talking about.

Comment: [Mine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/635634/m-babcock?tab=reputation).

Comment: Looks like it's the first time you've hit the repcap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you've reached the maximum reputation gained from upvotes in one day. You can only get 200 rep from upvotes before it cuts you off. It appears you are at 213, so the only rep you can get now are from accepts/bounties. In about an hour or so a new day will roll over, and you can earn rep from upvotes again. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: I could believe that but I have days (ok well 1 day) with up over 250 rep... why didn't it happen then? A few with between 200 and 250 though...

Comment: @M.Babcock Accepts and bounties don't count towards the cap.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. Should I just delete this question then since it seems to be a known non-issue?

Comment: @M.Babcock no, do not delete the question. It will just get posted as a duplicate and tagged properly. The question is fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help and explanation.