# Mobile site displays my downvoted questions (only for me in my user profile), why?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, down-votes, mobile-web

You can check your reputation history in the mobile version of SO but, I don't know why, it displays questions I downvoted. I've checked, I can't see downvoted question on other profile than mine.

There is no reputation gain in the first column, nor +1, nor -1.

Shouldn't be only accessible from the votes *tab* (ie: the dropdown list) ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe the [same as this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125065/gaining-losing-0-reputation-on-questions-ive-not-asked-or-answered) but in mobile world this time.

Comment: @Ben Nope this isn't related. I've just checked and I don't see recent downvoted question in the popup summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

There's a little filter that goes through and strips out "not worth displaying" events like this that wasn't getting applied on the mobile side, silly mistake.